# Prestashop Backend home page "access denied" error how to fix

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I'm using PrestaShop™ 1.5.6.2 version. First i'm working my local server. And now moved site to client sever. Now site is working fine and Back-end also working fine. But Admin Dashboard showing some access problem (check image).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ki2en.png

Answer (score 1):

I was having same issue in PS 1.7. As a super admin i was not able to edit pages. 
Design->Pages as Superadmin

Tried lots of other solutions but following did worked for me.

The following SQL-Query adds all missing entries from ps_authorization_role into ps_access for the role 1 which is the role for the administrator.

```
  INSERT INTO ps_access (id_profile, id_authorization_role) SELECT '1', ar.id_authorization_role FROM ps_authorization_role ar 
  LEFT JOIN ps_access a ON ar.id_authorization_role = a.id_authorization_role 
  WHERE a.id_authorization_role IS NULL
```

**Always make a backup of your database before running this query.**

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not logged with a super admin profile, you should check it. If you are the one who created this site, try to look at the database value in the "access" table, search for the tab id you are trying to see.

Comment: i'm check my profile. Profile Permissions are Supper Admin. Any Solution?

Comment: Do you have database access?

Comment: Thanks to your replay. See http://oi62.tinypic.com/1z354sp.jpg ps_access table. This value also correct.

Comment: That's weird. Maybe try to delete class_index.php in the cache folder, sometimes it can make some trouble. If it's not working, go to your AdminHomeController, inside getQuickLinks, and add var_dump($profile_access) after the line $profile_access = Profile::getProfileAccesses($this->context->employee->id_profile); Is it all the admin dashbord with this denied access display, or only one part?